# Not able to format the date in the ngGrid column

Tags: angularjs

Am new to angular and trying to implement ngGrid grid options. I am tryin to display a date column. But we are using hibernate and setting the date type as

```
type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate"
```

in the java class for our business logic.

Now am receiving this date as `[2014, 03, 01]` and this is displayed like a string in the grid. But I actually want to display it as `01-MAR-2014`.

Tried using cellTemplate and cellFilter in the columnDefs but could not succeed in getting the right format.

It would be great if I could get any pointers on how to format the column data in ngGrid or call a function in columnDefs that would return the date in the required format.

Comment: Can you show the `cellTemplate` that you tried?

Comment: Have you considered writing a custom filter or a custom directive (*seems overkill but often is a lot faster*)?
It is not that hard to do and it is actually pretty cool and fun. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: +1 for the filter (even directive will do). [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) may be of help in string -> date parsing.